# Insert values from two separate arrays into mysql table using Ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby, arrays

Suppose I have two different arrays.

> Emails = ["email@email.com", "email1@email.com", "email2@email.com"]
>
> Names = ["Name Surname", "Name1, Surname1", "Name2, Surname2"]

And I have a mysql-table called Contacts, which I want to insert each of the values into rows called Emails and Names. Each name and email should be inserted at their according indexes. So Emails[0] should be inserted along with Names[0], Emails[1] with Names[1] etc.

If there was only one array. I could do something like

> sql = "INSERT INTO Contacts (email) 
> VALUES 
> ('#{email}')
> Emails.each do |email| 
> email = email.sql 
> end

but now I have two arrays and I need to put them so that each email is associated according to the correct name. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `zip`:

```
 con.prepare "INSERT INTO Contacts(email, name) VALUES(?, ?)"
 Emails.zip(Names).each do |email,name|
   #insert into db
   con.execute(email,name) #assuming **con** is your connection object
 end
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know about zip.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this if you really want to iterate:

```
Email.zip(Names).each do |email, name|
  sql = "INSERT INTO Contacts (email, name) VALUES ('#{email}', '#{name)')"
end
```

alternatively, you can probably bulk insert using

```
sql = "INSERT INTO Contacts (email, name) VALUES (" + 
      Emails.zip(Names).map { |e, n|  "('#{e}', '#{n}')" }.join(",") + ")"
```

Looks kind of ugly, but you get the idea